# Can my spouse and I file jointly if I have an HSA and she has an FSA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa, fsa

My spouse has an FSA account, and I have an HSA account. We are on separate health insurance (mine is eligible for an HSA account). Are we allowed to file jointly or do we have to file separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're allowed to file jointly. To the best of my knowledge there's no situation where the law **forces** US tax residents to file MFS even if you want to file MFJ. MFS is always a taxpayer's choice (this is not necessary true for non-residents).